# Passing IOS native objects back to unity3d

Tags: iphone, ios, plugins, unity-game-engine

I implemented IOS plugin with couple of simple methods to interract my unity application with native static library.

The problem, I faced, is passing back native UI elements(objects) to unity.

F.e native SDK has method that creates badge (UIView), on the other hand I have button in unity (it could be GUI element or some 3d object, whatever)

I access this method from unity through my plugin, smth like:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]    
private static extern void XcodePlugin_GetBadgeView();
```

and following:

```
void XcodePlugin_GetBadgeView()
{
    // Generate native UIView 
    UIView *badge = [Badge badge];

    ???? Return UIView badge instance to unity (hm)?!
}
```

So I need something like:

```
[someViewOrObject addSubView:badge];
```

but inside unity.

I know there is ability to send message back to unity:

```
UnitySendMessage( "UnityCSharpClassName" , "UnityMethod", "WhateverValueToSendToUnity");
```

but WhateverValueToSendToUnity should be UTF8 string.

In conclusion:

Only one idea I have to pass coordinates from unity to native plugin, and then add badge to these coordinates(not sure this is best solution):

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]    
private static extern void XcodePlugin_AddBadgeViewToCoordinates(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for the badge coordinates, your idea seems fine.

If there are other things you'd like to get from iOS into Unity, I don't think there are many other options. The only other way that I can think of is to **save the data in a file** (eg, in NSTemporaryDirectory) and then pass the filename back as a UTF8String using UnitySendMessage. I've used this technique before (to pass images and JSON files) to Unity. Files in that directory get cleaned up automatically by iOS.

Comment: thx, that is helpfull. One other issue I have about IOS delegates. How I can pass notification to unity if something happend:
f.e unitySendMessage(someClass, someNotification) and can I call there unity callback or smth like: onSuccessSomthing() or onErrorSometing()