# Receiving message from client in Unity

Tags: ios, sockets, unity-game-engine, server, client

I'm trying to receive a message in Unity from a client connected. However, I do not find a way to create a server in Unity that accepts an external client (an iOS app) and reads messages.  Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832580/passing-ios-native-objects-back-to-unity3d

Comment: UnitySendMessage is this what u looking for?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm going to use an Objective-C app and TCP socket to send the string. I want my iOS app to connect to an IP and port (defined by the server in the Unity side).

Comment: -I do not find a way to create a server in Unity that accepts an external client -> create it on iOS side and pass data that you need back to Unity

Comment: I'm trying to create a c# server inside Unity directly. I'll keep you updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using socket with unity is a bit complicated and tricky but it is possible. I answered this question few days ago and see no need to re-post the code here. Here is a complete working Unity socket server code.

[Unity3d C# plugin to act as a socket server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/unity3d-c-sharp-plugin-to-act-as-a-socket-server/36526634#36526634)

Comment: the linked answer is indeed a gem

Comment: hi @Mark as a new user  it's essential that you TICK an answer.  cheers

Comment: @Mark You are welcome! Like joe said, you can accept it as the answer if this really helped you.